# Trying to have a horizontal scroll with 'overflowX' in MUI but it does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to have a proper-sized card with the horizontal scrollbar in a paper. I've been trying with 'overflow', however, it does not work in this case?

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Cards from './Cards';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    maxWidth: '100%',
    overflowX: 'auto',
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
}));

const Dashboard = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <Cards />
            <Cards />
            <Cards />
            <Cards />
            <Cards />
            <Cards />
            <Cards />
            <Cards />
            <Cards />

          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

This resulted in squeezing cards into a width of 100%. How can I make this scrollable?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of your card is `flex-shrink: 1` (Not enough space available? **shrink**)

> The `flex-shrink`: If the size of all flex items is larger than the flex container, items
> shrink to fit according to flex-shrink. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Next, by default `flex-basis` is `auto` + `flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Default value */` Items laid out in a **single line**.

**The output:**

- `2` cards => `2` cols.
- `9` cards => `9` "Squeeze" cols (Like your "buggy" screenshot).

**"Squeeze" = No overflow content = No scrollbar.**

Shrink Example:

```css
.flex_grid{
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.card{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex_grid">
  <div class="card"><h1>1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card"><h1>2</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card"><h1>3</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
   <div class="card"><h1>4</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card"><h1>5</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
   <div class="card"><h1>6</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

### One solution

1. Add [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) (Responsive => use `%`).
   For example:
   `flex-basis: 40%;` (Or use `auto` - related of the content inside the card).
2. Disable `shrink` by `flex-shrink: 0;`

Working example:

```css
.flex_grid{
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.card{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex-basis: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex_grid">
  <div class="card"><h1>1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card"><h1>2</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card"><h1>3</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```